# Java address book. How to prevent duplicate contacts in my code?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

```
switch(menuChoice) {

case 1: 
    System.out.println("Enter your contact's first name:\n");
    String fname = scnr.next();
    System.out.println("Enter your contact's last name:\n");
    String lname = scnr.next();
    Necronomicon.addContact(new Person(fname, lname));
    break;

// main truncated here for readability
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddressBook {

   ArrayList<Person> ArrayOfContacts= new ArrayList<Person>();

   public void addContact(Person p) {
      ArrayOfContacts.add(p);

 /* 
    for(int i = 0;  i < ArrayOfContacts.size(); i++) {
       if(ArrayOfContacts.get(i).getID() != p.getID())
           ArrayOfContacts.add(p);

    else 
       System.out.println("Sorry this contact already exists.");
    }       
  */

    }
}
```

---

```
public class Person {

   private String fName = null;
   private String lName = null;
   private static int ID = 1000;

   public Person(String fName, String lName) {       // Constructor I'm using to try and increment the ID each time a Person object is created starting at 1001.

     this.fName = fName;
     this.lName = lName;
     ID = ID + 1;
   }
}
```

I am trying to create an address book whereby each contact has a first name, last name and a unique ID.

My question is how to I prevent a user from entering in duplicate contacts with the same first and last name? Should I implement some kind of check in the addContact method or right in main? How?

Comment: Shouldn't you prevent the same id from being added? Normal address books have duplicate names

Comment: Good point. That is probably a better way to do it. Perhaps I could use the HashSet and just use the user ID's to prevent duplication.

Comment: You can use a `HashMap<Integer, Person>`

Comment: I've not yet encountered HashMaps in my studies Cricket. I'm assuming instead of using an arrayList to store my person objects I could use the HashMap? Would I pass the unique IDs as the Integer parameter?

Comment: For you case HashSet is the best option. By the way, there's the TreeSet collection which one doesn't accepts duplicate and order elements automatically. By the way, variables in Java should be camel case by convention. It should be arrayOfContacts.

Comment: @NickM I formulated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for keeping out duplicate ID's.

```
public void addContact(Person p) {

    for(int i = 0;  i < ArrayOfContacts.size(); i++) {
        Person contact = ArrayOfContacts.get(i);
        if(contact.getID() == p.getID()) {
            System.out.println("Sorry this contact already exists.");
            return; // the id exists, so we exit the method. 
        }
    }

    // Otherwise... you've checked all the elements, and have not found a duplicate
    ArrayOfContacts.add(p);

}
```

If you would like to change this code to keep out duplicate names, then do something like this

```
public void addContact(Person p) {
    String pName = p.getFname() + p.getLname();
    for(int i = 0;  i < ArrayOfContacts.size(); i++) {
        Person contact = ArrayOfContacts.get(i);
        String contactName =  contact.getFname() + contact.getLname(); 
        if(contactName.equals(pName)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry this contact already exists.");
            return; // the name exists, so we exit the method. 
        }
    }

    // Otherwise... you've checked all the elements, and have not found a duplicate
    ArrayOfContacts.add(p);

}
```

Comment: Nice thank you. I'll play with this code a little bit. Check my edit, would the way I'm using work if I could figure out how to increment each user Id correctly? I have to assign a unique ID to each person object starting at 1000. I figured I'd just increment by one every time I create a new person object. Problem is, I'm not incrementing correctly.

Comment: Each Person will have the same ID since you using a `static` variable. This is a "class variable", not an "instance" variable. If you would like an incrementing ID, you'll need a `private int id;` and set it in your constructor to `this.id = ++ID`.

Comment: Tried that but it's just giving every person the same ID. Maybe the way I'm testing to see which ID each object is getting is wrong. Ugh.

Comment: If you look at [developer033's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35677734/2308683), he does what I was hinting at

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I got it to increment correctly now! Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use HashSet and avoid any kind of loops to test it. HashSet is in charge of this function.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class AddressBook {

   Set<Person> listOfContacts = new HashSet<>();

   public void addContact(Person p) {
      if (!listOfContacts.add(p))
         System.out.println("Sorry this contact already exists.");    
   }
}
```

To increment ID property you should have 2 properties, 1 static and another one, and increment it in constructor. Look:

```
public class Person {
   private final int ID;
   private static int id = 1000;
   private String fName;
   private String lName;

   public Person(String fName, String lName) {       // Constructor I'm using to try and increment the ID each time a Person object is created starting at 1001.
      this.ID= ++id;
      this.fName = fName;
      this.lName = lName;   
   }
```

To make the HashSet not accept duplicate objects you should set which properties should not be duplicated in the class (Person in your case). Follows an example:

```
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 7;
      hash = 61 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.fName);
      hash = 61 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lName);
      return hash;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
         return false;

      final Person other = (Person) obj;
      if (!Objects.equals(this.fName, other.fName))
         return false;

      return Objects.equals(this.lName, other.lName);
   }
}
```

By the way, you can generate `equals` and `hashCode` methods using your IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.)

**EDIT**

Since you aren't able to use HashSet, I will show a version with ArrayList. By the way, you have to use `HashCode` and `equals` as I said to make it work well

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddressBook {

   List<Person> arrayOfContacts = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addContact(Person p) {
      if (listOfContacts.contains(p))
         System.out.println("Sorry this contact already exists.");

      else
         arrayOfContacts.add(p);    
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks developer. I got it to at least increment correctly now! I have been trying to avoid using the hash set stuff since we have not yet covered it in our class. It appears to make things a lot easier.

Comment: @NickM you could have said this in his post, anyway, I updated my answer. Take a look. Mark as answer if that answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashSet. For every user's name, add it to the HashSet.

For example:

```
HashSet<String> namesUsed = new HashSet<String>();

if (namesUsed.contains(userName)) {
    //do what you want here, if this is entered it means there is a duplicate
} else {
    namesUsed.add(userName); //add it to the list of used names
}
```

Comment: I don't think there needs to be an if-else since adding the same name 'has no effect"

Comment: @cricket_007 Maybe he wants to display a message for user informing that the contact already exists. But I would do different (to prevent call 2 methods - contains and add), since the add method returns a Boolean, I would do: If (!nameUsed.add(userName) { then display msg. }, so ELSE is not required.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going for. I commented above that address books are allowed to have duplicate names, though

Answer (score 0):

You should Override equals inside your Person class

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(fName.equals(obj.getfName()) && lName.equals(obj.getlName)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then just call:

```
if(!(person1.equals(person2))) {
//not a duplicate
}
```

And of course substitute the variables/objects with whatever objects you want.
You also should add getters and setters for last and first name.
Hope this helps!